# Getting ambiguous error on swift 4 migration

Tags: swift4

I have a class BorderedView class which is the subclass of UIView. After migrating to swift 4 I am getting few error in this class. Can't figure out whats wrong.Please see the image[image]

Comment: _"Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet"_... I reckon you have an extension with the same method, what you have gracefully forgotten about.

Comment: Thanks. You are right.